# How to paste duration of video on video thumbnail

Tags: video, thumbnails

I want to make a video thumbnail such that the length of the video is pasted on the thumbnail just like we see video thumbnails on YouTube.

Please help,
Muhammad Anas Khan.

Comment: You haven't specified what you wish to do that with (in terms of language.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the thumbnail image and the duration of the video then you have many options to overlay the duration onto the thumbnail image.

One example on the command line is to use ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/

If you prefer scripting then one way is to use PHP and its imaging capabilities: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you can use the RVideo gem.  The branch working with the latest version of ffmpeg is located here: http://github.com/howcast/rvideo